# How do I filter the contents of a json array, but keep the parent with jq?

Tags: array, json, jq

I have some JSON that looks like this:

```
{
  "Vpcs": [
    {
      "VpcId": "vpc-1",
      "OwnerId": "abc"
    },
    {
      "VpcId": "vpc-2",
      "OwnerId": "def"
    }
  ]
}
```

I just want the elements with `OwnerId!=abc`, but I want to keep the Vpcs parent array intact.

If I do `echo $JSON|jq -r '.Vpcs[]|select(.OwnerId!="abc")`, I get this:

```
{
  "VpcId": "vpc-2",
  "OwnerId": "def"
}
```

Which is close to what I want, but it doesn't have the parent array.  So, I thought maybe I should put the parent array inside the select statement, like this:

`echo $JSON |jq -r '.|select(.Vpcs[].OwnerId!="abc")'`

But that doesn't seem to filter the data that I want:

```
{
  "Vpcs": [
    {
      "VpcId": "vpc-1",
      "OwnerId": "abc"
    },
    {
      "VpcId": "vpc-2",
      "OwnerId": "def"
    }
  ]
}
```

How do I get the result to look like this:

```
{
  "Vpcs": [
    {
      "VpcId": "vpc-2",
      "OwnerId": "def"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If "rebuilding" your structure is an option you could do something like this

```
jq '.Vpcs[]|select(.OwnerId!="abc")|{Vpcs: [.]}'
```

Comment: This will work for me - thanks!
Note that I had !=abc instead of ==abc, but that's not a critical difference here.

Comment: Updated the condition!